# Symfony Session not working in Version 1.0.22

Tags: php, session, symfony1

After login the user, it redirect to Login successs page. That page i got the session(userid). But i click any other links or type any other url(same site), the session will distroyed. I also check it with normal $_SESSION[]; as well as $this->getUser()->setAttribute( ) ; method. I am new in symfony. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a new project, or you are maintaining an old one?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your cookies are enabled in your browser ?

Comment: Did you get any idea, Why this happened in first redirection. Or why the session vanished in first redirection.. I removed all session destroy codes from project...